# Using a variable inside an array accessor

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array item that is available as -

```
$this->form_fields->01_original_inventory_item->field_value;
```

I want to access this variable and the sister variables through the use of a variable like so. This would be a variable variable I believe.

```
    $i = 1;
    ${"supplement_inventory_item_ . $i"} = ${"this->
        form_fields->[$i]_original_inventory_item->field_value"};
    echo ${"supplement_inventory_item_ . $i"};
```

I am trying to use this [page from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in order to understand. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in setting my variable? There is no error, but the variable does not echo out. I am assuming I am setting A variable, but not the one I intend due to a mix up in my syntax.

My intent is to set -

```
$supplement_inventory_item_01 as $this->form_fields->01_original_inventory->field_value;
```

using a variable for the 01.

Comment: Have you tried removing the [ and ] from the second line? It does not seem to be an array..

Comment: @RhinoDevel That seems to turn _original_inventory_item into a variable though. My syntax highlighting is treating it like a single variable when the variable should just be the $i and then have the _original_inventory_item tacked on.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `$supplement_inventory_item_01 = $this->form_fields->01_original_inventory->field_value;`. Does it result in any errors? Check with `var_dump($supplement_inventory_item_01);`

Comment: Seems like you're missing the part where you pad $i with 0. Any reason you don't just use an array? `$supplement_inventory_item[$i] = ...`